# ProtractorJS_скрипт для определения будущей даты_не верно отрабатывает в тесте

Tags: javascript, test-automation, protractor

Всем добрый день,

Возникла проблема. Есть поле для ввода кол-ва дней. Есть поле, которое отображает будущую дату, которая равна текущей + данные с первого поля.

Написал код:

```
            var periodOfVacation = '28';

    //скрипт для определения будущей даты
    var dateToReturn = function() {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + periodOfVacation );
        var cur_date = function() {
            if(d.getDate()<10) {
                return '0' + d.getDate();
            } else {
                return d.getDate();
            };
        };
        var cur_month = function() {
            if((d.getMonth() + 1)<10) {
                return '0' + (d.getMonth() + 1);
            } else {
                return d.getMonth() + 1;
            };
        };
        var cur_year = d.getFullYear();
        return cur_date() + '.' + cur_month() + '.' + cur_year;  
    };

    //конец скрипта
    expect(formStepOne_page.fieldDateForReturn().getText()).toBe(dateToReturn());
```

Скрипт написан верно. Проверил в консоли браузера. Выводит на текущий момент 07.06.2017. Тест же у меня падает потому, что скрипт вычисляет как-то иначе и в итоге выводится:
Expected '07.06.2017' to be '22.02.2020'.

Кто с таким сталкивался? Помогите новичку, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Проблему нашел. Точнее не нашел, а поборол. Скрипт по всей видимости от куда-то тянет еще данные в тесте (разбираться нет времени). Если вместо переменной periodOfVacation вставить просто число 28, то скрипт в тесте отработает корректно. Это конечно не решение, так как скрипт не вынесен вверх, а находится по ходу дела в шаге самого теста.